# SharePoint Online: Oslo layout and InfoPath form web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, oslo

I'm using the Oslo site layout but each time I add an InfoPath form web part, it keeps increasing the left margin significantly (see green arrow below).  Is there a way to change this?  Thanks.

Before InfoPath form web part:
[image]

After InfoPath form web part:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, which has

- had its own [User Voice ticket](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13885845-infopath-form-web-part-has-a-display-error-issue-i) registered for official request from Microsoft
- been [recognized by TechNet staff who have reported the issue as a bug](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5e98c323-330f-4e06-a48f-4a637577f384/infopath-form-web-part-breaking-page-left-alignment).

Yet as of this date, the issue seemingly hasn't been fixed by MS.

It however can be reverted with a simple CSS adjustment. As working with SharePoint Online, probably the most effortless way to do this is to add a Script Editor Web Part to the page where you also have your InfoPath Form Web Part. To the Script Editor Web Part, add the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
#sideNavBox{
    display: none;
}
#contentBox{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>
```